# Undefined symbol OBJC Class in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, build, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to build my flutter project but I'm getting this error so I'm just wondering how can I fix this. This happens after adding the Cookie Manager plugin. I can run the app on an emulator and physical device without any problem but it gives me this error when I try to build it.

Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  lottie: ^1.2.1
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_hooks: ^0.16.0-nullsafety.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^0.13.1
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  flutter_html: ^2.1.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  jiffy: ^4.1.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  google_sign_in: ^5.1.1
  wp_json_api: ^3.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  flutter_tts: ^3.2.2
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.7
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  sticky_headers: ^0.2.0
  flutter_styled_toast: ^2.0.0
  flutter_math_fork: 0.4.2+2
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4
  webview_cookie_manager: ^2.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
```

[image]